# Conditional formatting with date and time

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have a problem on conditional formatting with date and time.

I have a cell `A1` that has date and time and I want to conditionally format its adjacent cell if the value of cell `A1` is greater than 3 days compared to today. Cell `A2` should show as "Follow-up Required" and cell colour should turn red. If cell value of `A1` is less than 3 days compared to today, no action is required.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional formatting "Use formula to determine which cells to format.

I don't completely understand your requirement but doing something like this in your adjacent cell should do it.

[image: conditional format]

The key concept here is that conditional formatting requires a true/false input. Most of the time we want to conditionally format based on the value in the cell itself. However using the formula section allows the format of any cell to be determined by any formula that evaluates to true or false.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to @Pynner's answer, but addresses " Cell A2 should show as "Follow-up Required". Enter:

```
=IF(NOW()>A1+3,"""Follow-up Required""","")
```

in `A2` and copy down (assuming you have several `'A1'` dates). This provides the required text and can also be used for the conditional format, with "Format only cells that contain" and Cell Value equal to `="""Follow-up Required"""`
Note that NOW() may need to be refreshed (eg <kbd>F9</kbd>) and this takes '3 days' as 72 hours.